# Enable work.com settings in Scratch Org Definition File with SalesforceDX

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, work.com

I am trying to enable work.com Thanks and Skills Settings in Scratch Org. Do you know is it possible to put the configuration/settings in scratch org's definition file?

Answer (score 2):

Starting Winter '20 release, WorkDotComSettings are supported both in the Metadata API and in the Scratch Org source tracking. You can see it in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage).

The documentation for WorkDotComSettings  is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_WorkDotComSettings.htm).

You can either deploy the metadata settings via the Metadata API, or add the same settings in the scratch definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "My Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "settings": {
    "workDotComSettings": {
        "enableWorkThanksPref": true,
        "enableProfileSkills": true
     }
  }
}
```

You can then enable the other Work.com settings you need by adding them according the documentation name.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not possible with scratch org's definition file.

In case you want to automate enabling of the settings, you could write a small script and enable them using [`Puppeteer`](https://twitter.com/wadewegner/status/1082481589827694592?lang=en) as stated by wade wegner on twitter.