# Enable ProfileSkillEndorsement/ProfileSkillUser/ProfileSkill for Scratch Org

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Any idea how to get Custom Objects like ProfileSkillEndorsement, ProfileSkill & ProfileSkillUser in my Scratch Org. I have created a Scratch Org but during my metadata deploy I am getting the Error as below for Profiles:

**"error": "In field: object - no CustomObject named ProfileSkillEndorsement found",**

There should be some setting that would enable the Object in my Scratch Org as there is no "__c"

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are standard objects seems to be part of [`Work.com`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334792&language=en_US&type=1) feature in Salesforce, you can enable them in classic by navigating in setup: `Build` -> `Customize` -> `Work.com` -> `Work.com Settings` and enable `Skills Settings`:

[image]

---

In case you want to automate enabling of the settings, you could write a small script and enable them using [`Puppeteer`](https://twitter.com/wadewegner/status/1082481589827694592?lang=en) as stated by wade wegner on twitter.

Comment: Thanks @Raul Is there a way to have incorporated in the scratch Org ?

Comment: I lookup up, does not seems to be possible to do this via [Scratch Org Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) file. There is an old question with that [Enable work.com settings in Scratch Org Definition File with SalesforceDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239698/enable-work-com-settings-in-scratch-org-definition-file-with-salesforcedx?rq=1)

Comment: So I guess you would have to enable setting manual after scratch org creation and before doing a push.

Comment: Unfortunately Yes :(

Comment: I added some more details in answer, you can use `Puppeteer` to automate things and incroporating in your DX flow

Comment: I will surely check it out... And agreed your ans is correct. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting Winter '20 release, WorkDotComSettings are supported both in the Metadata API and in the Scratch Org source tracking. You can see it in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage).

The documentation for WorkDotComSettings  is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_WorkDotComSettings.htm).

You can either deploy the metadata settings via the Metadata API, or add the same settings in the scratch definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "My Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "settings": {
    "workDotComSettings": {
        "enableProfileSkills": true
     }
  }
}
```

You can then enable the other Work.com settings you need by adding them according the documentation name.